# Drive encryption with OS on SSD and /home on HDD in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, encryption

I am trying to prepare an Ubuntu workstation for a colleague, which for storage has both a smaller SSD and also a larger HDD.

I would like to use the SSD for the root partition, and the HDD for the /home partition, and I would also like to ensure that the user's data is encrypted.

I am aware that Ubuntu 18.04 unfortunately does not support only homedir encryption, but drive encryption instead.

In the installer/disk partitioner, I selected the option for encryption, and set an encryption password, and then set up the desired partitions on the SSD and HDD (the computer is single boot, Ubuntu only).

After the installation completed, and I rebooted, I was not prompted for the encryption password, but Ubuntu loaded straight to the user login screen. I am not convinced that the installer has actually set up encryption in this slightly atypical setup.

Is it possible to encrypt the home partition/drive now, after the OS installation, or alternatively, could anyone guide me through exactly what I need to do in the disk partitioner?

Comment: I suggest you search “encrypt home” on Ask Ubuntu and look at the most recent posts. I found some guides to doing what you want but it does appear to add some risks to your installation. Just be aware there are some old posts with answers that may not be the best advice today.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It turns out that in the "Related questions" there is a link to [How do I install 18.04 using full disk encryption with two drives (SSD/HDD)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034079/how-do-i-install-18-04-using-full-disk-encryption-with-two-drives-ssd-hdd) which might be a better fit for a "duplicate question redirect" perhaps? (I didn't find that question when trying to search the site before posting.)