# Full disk encryption for separated hard drives

Tags: partitioning, encryption, luks

I’m asking if there is possibility to make a full disk encryption for two hard drives.
We want to use:

1. `/dev/sda` for the root file system `/` including boot grub …
2. `/dev/sdb` for `/home`.

The question is can we make a full disk encryption for both disks?
And if not, is there any chance to maximise the encryption for both disks?

Edit: I want to install Ubuntu desktop. Eather 21.04 or 20.04. I flashed the iso using dd. My searches leads me to use FDE with separated `/home` partition.

Comment: Please edit your question and include more details. You should give clear details about the problem you are experiencing as well as details about your research and attempts to solve this problem.  Explain why what you've found is not working for you.

Comment: I’m using Ubuntu 21.04 . I burned the iso file in an USB using dd. And I don’t know about ubuntu installers. I will edit the question to add OS.

Comment: Well. Sorry about that. It’s a Ubuntu 21.04 desktop iso.

Comment: Full disk encryption with separate home partition is what you want to do. You can encrypt `/dev/sdb` as a separate LUKS-encrypted device and then mount it under `/home` at boot. You may just have to enter the passphrase for both disks separately on boot.

Comment: Well. I think the issue with separated home partition that even it’s a separated partition it is located under the same LUKS extended partition. I followed one of tutorials. And for some reason. I can’t mount the second hard drive as /home. .

Comment: If you already made that. Please provide me the steps to follow. I will try it. Maybe there is something missing in the steps I followed before.

Comment: I managed to make it successfully bu following https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034079/how-do-i-install-18-04-using-full-disk-encryption-with-two-drives-ssd-hdd#1035703

Comment: Yes. It does. And everything seems to work perfectly.